# Use self while declaring default value in dataclass

Tags: python, class, python-dataclasses

I want to create a python `dataclass` where one of the variables is based on the two other variables.
e.g.

```
@dataclass
class phone_number:
    number: str
    country_code: str = "+1 "
    full_number: str = country_code + number
```

So when I call `phone_number.full_number` I get for example `"+1 123456789"`.

But it is also important for me to be able to pass a already full phone number if I needed to as so `phone = phone_number(number="", full_number="+1 123456789")`.

Also while I am at it, is it possible to make the variable `number` and `full_number`, mutually exclusive, so if given number, I don't need to pass `full_number` and the other way around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, it's possible by using a sentinel as a default value (I'm just using `None` here to keep the types simple). That way, you can check in the `__post_init__` whether a custom `full_number` was passed or not:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Optional


@dataclass
class phone_number:
    number: str
    country_code: str = "+1 "
    full_number: Optional[str] = None

    def __post_init__(self):
        if self.full_number is None:
            self.full_number = self.country_code + self.number
```

And here are some usage examples:

```py
>>> phone_number("123"))
phone_number(number='123', country_code='+1 ', full_number='+1 123')

>>> phone_number("123", country_code="+44 "))
phone_number(number='123', country_code='+44 ', full_number='+44 123')

>>> phone_number("123", full_number="789"))
phone_number(number='123', country_code='+1 ', full_number='789')

>>> phone_number("123", country_code="+44 ", full_number="789"))
phone_number(number='123', country_code='+44 ', full_number='789')
```

Comment: So if I now do phone_number.full_number I wil still get self.country_code + self.number?

Comment: as long as you didn't supply a custom `full_number` when creating the instance, yes. I'll add an example for each case. I also had a bug in there I needed to fix, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a `property`:

```
@dataclass
class phone_number:
    number: str
    country_code: str = "+1 "

    @property
    def full_number(self):
        return self.country_code + self.number
```

but at this point you might as well just use a normal class, especially due to the other 2 requirements:

```
from typing import Optional

class phone_number:
    def __init__(self, number: Optional[str] = None,
                 country_code: str = "+1",
                 full_number: Optional[str] = None):
        if number and full_number:
            raise ValueError('number and full_number are mutually exclusive')
        self.number = number
        self.country_code = country_code
        self._full_number = full_number or f'{country_code} {number}'

    @property
    def full_number(self):
        return self._full_number


print(phone_number(number='1234567').full_number)
# +1 1234567
print(phone_number(full_number='1234567').full_number)
# 1234567
```